# setTimeout not functioning as xpected?

Tags: node.js, azure, dom-events, settimeout, setinterval

I am using socket.io to send some data continuously from server to client. So I was using the `setTimeout` function to send the data periodically, and the sleep time is not constant so am not using `setInterval`, but `setTimeout` is not working. I am using service bus to get some data from my worker role which am forwarding to the client at regular intervals. Here is my code:

```
var sleepTime;

function requestQueue() {

sleepTime = 0;

console.log("REQUEST QUEUE STARTED");

console.log("SEND to WORKER ROLE");
// send the request to worker role
var broadcastMessage = {}
broadcastMessage.Channel = "World";
broadcastMessage.BufferSize = 10;     

sendMessage(socketToWorkerRole, broadcastMessage)

receivePeriodicRecordsQueue(workerRoleToSocket);
}
```

////

```
function receivePeriodicRecordsQueue(queue) {

serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage(queue, function (error, receivedMessage) {
    if (!error) {
        if (receivedMessage != null) {
            var messageBody = receivedMessage.body;

            if (messageBody != null) {

                // Lots of processing and calculating sleep time
                  
                    // SET TIMEOUT
                    if (sleepTime != 0) {
                        console.log("SLEEP TIME:" + sleepTime);
                        setTimeout(function () { requestQueue(); }, sleepTime);
                    }

                      // sending data to client through socket
                    io.sockets.emit('broadcast', recordsQueue);

                }

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log(error);
    }
})

}
```

I am basically a C# programmer, very new to JS. Please let me know if my implementation of `setTimeout` is wrong. Essentially I want the `requestQueue` method to be called periodically using a variable sleep time

EDIT ANSWER:

In my case it was a silly issue. I was using the sleep time in seconds instead of milliseconds. `setTimeout` requires milliseconds.  I have marked Scott's as the answer because I thought the async module is pretty useful and can be used as a replacement for `setTimeout` and for a lot of other functionalities if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could benefit from some control flow in your app.

Take a look at the async module.  It is straight forward and will eliminate the need to use setTimeout.

https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Great! Looks like i can leverage this, do u have any idea on what function i need to use to replicate the setTimeout behaviour?

Comment: Wait! Suppose if i am using any of "forever" or "whilst" from the async module then my execution control would be stuck in it right? I mean clients will be making requests to the socket, so i dont want those requests to be stalled because the execution control is stuck in the "forerver" method.

Comment: I would go with the queue object:

queue(worker, concurrency)

Creates a queue object with the specified concurrency. Tasks added to the queue will be processed in parallel (up to the concurrency limit). If all workers are in progress, the task is queued until one is available. Once a worker has completed a task, the task's callback is called.